# does SpringBoot embedded server Fully support java EE?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, server, microservices

I need help understanding, so SpringBoot has an embedded server like tomcat or jetty ik
but when it comes down to full java EE features ik Jboss is a server that supports that, while tomcat has some limations. So does that mean when i need to use those features i would need to deploy my project to an external server (Jboss) and not use the embedded one within springBoot? Ik the Jar file provided is an embedded server but tomcat has some limitations so does it mean i need to create a war file and upload to jboss so i can access those features?

tried looking on google this what i got "Tomcat doesn't implement all the features required of a Java EE application server. The accurate title for Tomcat would be either “web server” or “servlet container”

so does this mean if i want to use features supported from jboss i would need to package my project as a war file so i dont have to use the embedded server within spring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Springboot does only support some features from JEE, When it comes to some features needed from Full Java EE then Jboss provides that. SpringBoot by default is using Tomcat or some other web server which provides only some limit for JEE while Jboss or any other Full JEE application server provides the full Service.